# Debugging JavaScript "Breakout" game, weird lags on ball (beginner)

Tags: javascript, debugging, lag

I'm viewing this code for two days now and it really doesn't seem to me like anything is wrong at all. Tried changing the code in many ways but had little to no success with the lag issue of the ball. something clearly is wrong because the ball has this weird lag (sometimes it behaves normally but most of the times it has this odd lag that is causing changes in speed of the ball.)

This are two of the main functions that make the ball move and both seem OK to me.

```
    function ball(){ //gets called 1000 times per second 
        if(lifeCount==0){
            ctx.clearRect(0,0,900,600);
            ctx.drawImage(youLose,0,0,900,600);
            return;
        }
        else{
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.clearRect(xBall-(r+1),yBall-(r+1),2*r+2,2*r+2);
            ballCollision(); //function
            ctx.arc(xBall,yBall,r,0,2*Math.PI, true);
            ctx.fillStyle = "#c82124";
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.stroke();
            bricksHit(); //function (no lag)
            bricksDraw(); //function (no lag)
            ballPowerUp(); //function (no lag)
        }
    }

    function ballCollision(){
        if(startDirection === 1) //random start, ball begins moving "left"
            xBall += -xSpeed;

        if(startDirection === 2) //random start, ball begins moving "right"
            xBall += xSpeed;

        if(xBall>=canvas.width-r) //right wall collision
            xSpeed = -xSpeed

        if(xBall<=0+r) //left wall collision
            xSpeed = -xSpeed

        if(yBall<=0+r)//top wall collision
            ySpeed = -ySpeed;

        if(xBall>=x-(paddleW/2) && xBall<=x+(paddleW/2) && (yBall <= canvas.height-paddleH-r && yBall >= canvas.height-paddleH-r-4)) //bottom paddle collision
            ySpeed = -ySpeed;

        yBall += ySpeed;

        if(yBall>=canvas.height-r){
            lifeCount--;

            if(lifeCount>0)
                initBall(); //another chance if you still have lives left
        }
    }

    canvas.onmousemove = function() {
        if(lifeCount==0){
            return;
        }
        else{
            padd();
        }
    }
```

There is probably some rookie mistake made in the code somewhere that I just can't seem to find or I don't know what else may be causing this. If any of you has any suggestions please let me know.

also if anyone would like to see how the game actually "lags" here's a link of html file: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1A1H1MiKpIutj9Z4kdrDunHZHHYeWNfl3

Thanks in advance!

Comment: _"`//gets called 1000 times per second`"_ by what?  This is almost certainly the issue - 1000 times a second is a _lot_, and is probably not actually being called this frequently - while it might be designed that way, the browser is almost certainly throttling it.

Comment: @JamesThorpe if I call it less frequently ball moves too slowly (and if I call it less frequently but increase how many pixels it moves by it stops being smooth.) for this I use "setInterval(ball,1);".

Comment: It's not a direct answer to your problem, but if you're doing this sort of work, you might want to look into [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) instead - it's much more suited to this sort of stuff and aims to run at a steady 60fps etc.

Comment: @JamesThorpe thanks. Should I just change all intervals for request animation frames? never used it so I'm not too sure how much of a hassle it is to change everything. Will look into it later today. thanks again!